# 3D surface plot with different length of arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, matplotlib-3d

I want to create one 3D surface plot while the length of the arrays for each iteration is different hence different length of axis. I have a working example here for better understanding. You notice that `J` is dependent on `M` so the length of arrays in each iteration is different. When I plot this, it doesn't produce surface plots but just a 2d plot stretched over the `J` axis. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("M")
ax.set_ylabel("J")
ax.set_zlabel("K")

for M in range(1, 5):
    liss = []
    for J in range(M, M*3):
        K = M + J
        liss.append(K)
    
    L = np.array([liss])
    J = np.array([i for i in range(M, M*3)])
    M, J = np.meshgrid(M, J)

    surf = ax.plot_surface(M, J, L, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.7)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5, pad=0.1);
```

[image]

Comment: Because the elements in `M` is a constant

Comment: @HMH1013 Is there anyway that I can plot this in surface area when the array lengths are different? I don't think the way I'm doing is the best (even correct) way!